# Verify burned CD image

Tags: iso-image, burning, compact-disc, verification

Is there a way to verify a CD image (.iso) after it has been burned (and either the CD burning software does not have a "verify" option, or it was not used at the time of burning)?

I tried ripping the CD using dd and comparing the md5sum of that image and the original, but they don't match. I didn't really expect them to, but I'm pretty sure this disc burned without errors (I just want to be sure since this is a master disc to be sent off to be duplicated).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[ImgBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) has the ability to do this.

> - Verify - Check a disc is 100% readable. Optionally, you can also have ImgBurn compare it against a given image file to ensure the actual data is correct

Answer (score 0):

[Nero can do that.](http://www.nero.com/eng/downloads-nero9-free.php) It has a checkmark (turned on by default) when you burning a CD.

Comment: I know that many CD burning programs have an option to verify immediately after burning, but I want to compare a disc that has already been burned with the source image.